# Macro for Word: Hide lines starting with certain words

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a .docx file that contains thousands of lines that are of 3-line repetition as follows:

```
[A]xxxxxx
[B]yyyyyy
[C]
```

What I want to achive with a marco is to:

> 1. Copy *yyyyyy* from the line starting with *[B]* after *[C]*
> 2. Hide lines starting with *[A]* or *[B]*

Function 2 is the primary automated action I want to achive while Function 1 is optional (better to have!).

I personally don't have any knowledge on Marcos, it would be great that anyone can provide some guidance on this.

Regards,

Comment: Please take a moment to consult the site's [help] about what kind of questions may be asked on Stack Overflow and how to ask them effectively. Please note that this is not a free coding service nor a tutorial site. It targets professional and enthusiast programmers (foreknowledge therefore required). The best advice I can give you to get started would be to record the necessary steps in a macro.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need a macro for this - just two *wildcard* Find/Replace operations, where:

```
Find = (\[A\]*\[B\])(*)(\[C\]*)(^13)
Replace = \1\4\3\2
```

then:

```
Find = \[A\]*\[B\]*^13
Replace = ^&
```

with the replacement text set as hidden for the second F/R. You could, of course, record the F/R operations as a macro.